# $this in late static bindings in php

Tags: php, static

I am trying to understand LSB in php and stumbled on to this [late static binding in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060431/late-static-binding-in-php).I don't understand how `$this` and `static::` are resolved in the example. `A::test()` has both `$this->foo()` and `static::foo()`.

Here is my current understanding.
1) `$this` refers to calling object in non static context. 
2)`static::` refers to calling class in static context.

Now `b->test()` should contain `b->foo()`(this should actually fail?) and `c->test()` should contain `c->foo()` for their corresponding `$this->foo()`. Or to put it in another way, how does `$this` behave in inherited method? Finally, how does `static::` behave in non static context?